# Log request and response with Event Listener in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, event-listener

I am trying to log a Request and Response with an Event listener in Symfony2.

I've registered the following Service:

```
class LoggerListener
{

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager
     */
    private $documentManager;

    public function __construct(DocumentManager $documentManager)
    {

        $this->documentManager = $documentManager;
    }

    public function onKernelResponse(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();

        if ( ! is_array($controller)) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! $controller instanceof BaseAPIController) {
            return;
        }


        $log = new ServerRequestsLog();
        $log->setRequest($request);
        $log->setRequest($response);


    }
}
```

with this configuration:

```
  example.response_listener:
      class: Example\ServerBundle\EventListener\LoggerListener
      arguments: ["@doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager"]
      tags:
          - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

How can I get the Request and the Response in this action? I think I can get the Request if I will inject the Request service. but what about the response?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can [read here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#component-http-kernel-event-table), `kernel.response` event object, that passed to your listener is `FilterResponseEvent`. This object has both `getRequest` and `getResponse` methods. So your code should look like:

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $response = $event->getResponse();

    $log = new ServerRequestsLog();
    $log->setRequest($request);
    $log->setRequest($response);
    //....Save it with document manager, etc.
}
```